# Focus on page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set focus on a certain ID in the page if a CSS class is present. However the code that I have doesn't work and I am not certain why?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('body').hasClass('message')) {
        $('#maincontent').focus();
    }
});
```

HTML: 
The Anchor in the page to set focus:

```
<a name="maincontent" tabindex="-1" id="maincontent"/>
```

If this div is present in page:

```
<div class="message success"><p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Your submission has been received.</p></div>
```

Comment: When using `hasClass`, don't include the `.`

Comment: My bad, I don't have the period locally. Even so it still is not working.

Comment: What is `maincontent`'s contents?

Comment: Show the html you're working with.

Comment: `body` doesn't have class `message`

Comment: Can I check somehow if the entire page, that being the <body> content has the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('body .message').length) {
        $('#maincontent').focus();
    }
});
```

The body doesn't have class message in your HTML.

Comment: Like magic, that did it. Had no idea you could reference the body like that. What if I want to check for multiple classes? Like success, fail,....

Comment: Depends on if they all need to evaluate to true, or if just one. You can use an `or` statement in one case `$('body .message').length || $('body .fail').length` or you can comma separate if you only care if there's at least one of the group. `$('body .message, body .fail').length`

Comment: Odd think is happening, it is setting the focus to #maincontent all the time. Even if the class .message is not in the page.

Comment: Have you tried making a jsfiddle to send an example? It must exist if it's focusing.

Answer (score 3):

So, basically what you want to do is go to the anchor, not focus the element right? Because you can't focus on an empty "**a**" element.

To set focus on an anchor try this

```
function goToAnchor(id) {
    var url = location.href;  //Save down the URL
    location.href = "#" + id; //Go to the anchor.
}​
```

And then you can do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('body').find('.message').length > 0) {
        goToAnchor('maincontent');
    }
});
```

To check if the body has an element with a specific class just do this

```
$('body').find('.message').length > 0
```

And here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pedromendessk/9rpb7j5g/).

Hope this helped,

Comment: For last example, `.has('.message')` should be faster than `find('.message')`, as it aborts after first match.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is less efficient than it should be. It searches for all `class="message"` elements, *then* filters it based on being a descendant of `body`. As `body` is the default scope of a jQuery search, you should just search for `.message` and count the responses.

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.message').length) {
        $('#maincontent').focus();
    }
});
```

Modern browser implement searches by class very efficiently (almost as fast as ID selectors), so might as well stick to just the class selector.

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you have a Div like this

```
<div class="myClass" id="myElement"></div>
```

You can select the id by using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('#myElement').hasClass('myClass')) { 
//Some Code
}});
```

Comment: It already has a valid attribute for selection (i.e. class="message"). On modern browsers a class selector is almost as fast as an ID selector so make no odds.

Comment: Just an example mate don't worry about it.